# Load basic file

Tags: javascript

In `app/config/` I have a file called `connection.properties` with my API url

```
  `API=http://localhost:12345/context/api`
```

How do I load it to my controller in `app/src/folder/` ?

Controller code:

```
// REST API Base URL
var baseUrl = I need the URL from the properties file here;
```

Comment: You need to export API variable and then import it in the other file. `export const API='http://localhost:12345/context/api'`; `import { API } from './path to your-file'`

Comment: @kboul isnt that Angular and not Angularjs?

Comment: It's simply es6...